# OPENSSL_1.0.0 not found when running PyPy 4.0.1 on Amazon Linux (AWS EC2)

Tags: linux, python, openssl, amazon-ec2

I want to run PyPy 4.0.1 on Amazon Linux (AWS EC2), and then downloaded and unzipped the tar.bz file. Also, I created the symbolic links to fix problems, such as

```
pypy: error while loading shared libraries: libbz2.so.1.0
```

Here are symbolic link I created:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6 /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0
sudo ln -s /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1k /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1k /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

However, it seems that PyPy will check the version of those libraries. I got error messages:

```
pypy: /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /path/to/pypy-4.0.1-linux64/bin/libpypy-c.so)
pypy: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /path/to/pypy-4.0.1-linux64/bin/libpypy-c.so)
```

Does anyone have a solution to resolve this problem? I would be grateful if you can provide any suggestions or useful information.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for viable solutions, here are two solutions:

1. Download and install PyPy 2.4 via yum.

   sudo yum --enablerepo=amzn-preview install pypy
2. Download the Portable PyPy.

   https://bitbucket.org/squeaky/portable-pypy/downloads/pypy-4.0.1-linux_x86_64-portable.tar.bz2

Comment: This seems to be endorsed by PyPy; see the `[1]` note in [the installation page](https://pypy.org/download.html#installing), which links to [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy#portable-pypy-distribution-for-linux), which links to the files in bitbucket.